# Sort NSSortDescriptor by entity index Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nssortdescriptor

Is it possible to sort fetch request by creation order (by index) without adding of any special columns like date or id?

I am trying to do something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Table")
        let sectionSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "self", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptors = [sectionSortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicateSuccess
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 10
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
```

Comment: If you want to sort by `creationTime`, just add that field and sort by it.

Comment: @Sulthan I don't want to add any useless fields only to make sort by these fields. That is why I wrote **without adding of any special columns like date or id**. I want to sort by index like in SQL

Comment: Core Data is not SQL, it's an object graph. If there is some index, it's an implementation detail. The index does not have to be in any specific order.

Comment: @Sulthan ok I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS there is no such field as 'self' for a table record. You must create a 'date' or 'id' field if you wish to sort by date or id.

Comment: so there is no possibility to sort like in sql? without creating useless fields?

Comment: Correct. But SQL auto creates the useless fields for you, so at least with CoreData you have a choice! :o)

Comment: thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, it is not possible